# Cannot connect to mysql running of remote machine

Tags: java, mysql, linux

I am trying to connect to mysql using workbench from my local system.
But, i am getting the below error.[image]

I checked that whether mysql service is running on my remote machine using:

```
service mysql status;
service mysqld status;
```

Also, when am trying to connect to mysql programmatically i am getting below error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create connection:Could not connect: Connection refused: connect
```

and i found that its running . Please correct me here if i am missing anything.

Comment: Firewalled port maybe? Try doing a telnet to the IP and port and see if you get connection refused. If you do the port isn't open on the remote box.

Comment: @Vasan using telnet i am getting connection refused.

Comment: Yup, you need to change firewall config on remote host to open the port then. Search superuser.com with your remote box OS name and "open port", you'll get what to do. Or if you don't get it, you can post a fresh question there since it is OT for SO.

Comment: @Vasan many thanks i got my answer not its working.